# Turning white background transparent, but keeping dropshadow?

Tags: adobe, photoshop

In an image like this, I want to remove the white background but keep the grayness of the dropshadow. Reomving mapping the actual image is not a problem!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I enden up doing instead after lots and lots of trial and error.

Duplicate the layer with the paper in it.
Invert the new layer. 
Painting the "paper-part" clear white

Using the inverted layer as a mask on the first layer.

Worked like a charm, perfect masking!

Answer (score 1):

Two options that I can think of:
a) Edit the image in photoshop and make the background transparent.
b) Overlay the "white" background w/ a div overlay that has a white background.

a is the preferred option.  Post a comment on this reply if you need me to do this for you.

Comment: that's really genearous of you, but I'm really looking for some way to  "map the whiteness to transparency, so that all gray stuff get's transparent"

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand.  Let me know if one of the following helps you:
http://www.imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=2874
http://www.imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=2875

Answer (score 0):

did you make that image? Why not make the image on a transparent background?

But if you didn't make the image, I don't know if you really can unless you plan on putting it on another whitish background because the dropshadow itself is going to be a little transparent and whatever is underneath it will show through.

Comment: Haha, I figured I would just state the obvious to make sure